# Expected number of pairs of consecutive sixes in after $n$ throws of a dice

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Suppose we throw a six-faced dice $n$ times.

Let's define the random variable X as the number of times two consecutive sixes appear, so $$ X = | \{i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\} : r_i = r_{i+1} = 6\} | $$

where $r_i$ is the $i$th result in our sequence of throws.

How do I calculate $E[X]$?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you set up the indicator variable?

Comment: I tried by setting $X_i$ as the even that we get a double six in $r_i, r_{i+1}$. This way, we have that $X = \sum X_i$, and for linearity of expectation $E[X] = \sum E[X_i] = (n-1) \frac{1}{36}$, but I'm not convinced and I couldn't find a solution online

Comment: That works, and its exactly what I typed up. Can you add that as a solution?

As a follow-up, find the variance of $X$.

Comment: yep, I will add that as solution as soon as stack overflow lets me. (I have to wait 8 minutes). Will try and find $Var[X]$, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $I_k$ be the indicator variable that both $k$ and $k+1$ are 6's.

> Clearly $E[I_k] = \frac{1}{36}$.
>  Show that $ X = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} I_k$.
>  Hence, by the linearity of expectation, $ E[X] = E [ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} I_k ] = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} E[I_k] = \frac{n-1}{36}$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)